# Is there a verb in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire

I hit this line:

> Plaisir multiplié par la découverte d'étonnants rapports entre ces mondes éloignés de nous par la distance ou le temps, et celui où nous vivions.

Seems to me there's no verb there, am I right to say so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are verbs, of course, but you mean is there a main verb allowing for a main clause. No, there isn't. This is a sentence fragment.

I would guess that it's a continuation of a sentence that introduces the *plaisir*, something like:

> Nous cherchons le plaisir.

If strictly following formal conventions, this should be joined to the next by a comma or colon, but it's common enough to break it with a period for stylistic effect despite leaving a sentence fragment.

Comment: So there aren't finite verbs?

Comment: @Acccumulation Not that can be parsed as the predicate of the main clause. "vivions" is clearly finite but is in a relative clause.

Comment: Note that this is not some special rule about French; the same can be done in English, for example: *I ate an apple. A red apple.* Technically there is no verb in that second sentence, but the implied meaning is *That apple was red.*

Comment: Domino is correct, it is the same phenomenon. Only in French it is used as a full-fledged stylistic device whereas English tends to reserve such constructs for brief afterthoughts, often pithy and emphatic.

Comment: @Deipatrous Eh, I guess. I think it's pretty common in both languages as a stylistic device. A device whose efficacy is owed to... etc. :)

Answer (score 5):

The sentence is misquoted, the original one is, in context:

> Le théâtre de Federico Garcia Lorca m'aura plus appris sur l'âme secrète de l'Espagne que vingt voyages faits en touriste. Tchékhov et Tolstoï m'ont révélé des aspects de l'âme russe qui restent vrais. Les Mémoires de Saint-Simon ont fait revivre pour moi une France qui n'est plus, tout comme les romans de Hawthorne ou de Mark Twain m'ont permis d'imaginer une Amérique disparue. **Plaisir accru par la découverte d'étonnantes ressemblances entre ces mondes, éloignés de nous par la distance ou le temps, et celui où nous vivons.** Les êtres humains ont tous des traits communs. Les passions des rois dans Homère ne sont pas si différentes de celles des généraux dans une coalition moderne. Quand je faisais un cours sur Marcel Proust aux étudiants de Kansas City, les fils des fermiers américains se reconnaissaient dans ces personnages français. « Après tout, il n'y a qu'une race : l'humanité. »

[André Mauroy](https://www.anthologiablog.com/post/andr%C3%A9-maurois-des-livres-et-des-biblioth%C3%A8ques#:%7E:text=Plaisir%20accru%20par%20la%20d%C3%A9couverte,g%C3%A9n%C3%A9raux%20dans%20une%20coalition%20moderne.)

An explicit conjugated verb at its core is not mandatory for a French sentence. Here, the author is simply expressing a thought related to the pleasure he gets from reading books. The title of a book or of a chapter of a book would follow the same grammatical rules.

If you really wan't a verb in that sentence, you can prefix it with *J'éprouve un* or *On éprouve un*:

> ***J'éprouve un** plaisir accru par la découverte d'étonnantes ressemblances entre ces mondes et celui où nous vivons.*

Comment: thank you, indeed the source i quoted has adapted a bit from the original text.

Answer (score 1):

Le verbe est **multiplié** et son sujet est *plaisir*.

Le fait qu'il soit au participe passé est inhabituel mais grammaticalement, ça fonctionne.

Comment: The subject of *multiplié* is *la découverte*. The object is *plaisir*.

Comment: But here multiplié is a *participe passé*, i.e. a past participle, served as an adjective, not a verb of a subject, right?

Comment: @LukeSawczak, je dirais plutôt que la phrase est à la voix passive, donc selon moi le sujet grammatical est bien *plaisir*. Tourné à la voix active, *la découverte multiplie le plaisir*, le sujet est bien *la découverte*.

Comment: @athos, le participe passé n'est pas toujours utilisé comme adjectif. Ici, c'est le cas de *éloignés*, mais pas celui de *multiplié* selon moi.

Comment: Multiplié est ici un participe adjectif. Il n'a donc aucune valeur verbale : la locution "éloignés de nous" pourrait sans la moindre difficulté se trouver remplacée par "lointains".

Comment: I would say this is a shorthand for "[Le] plaisir [est] multiplié par la [...]"

Comment: A participle is not a finite form, which makes it syntactically deficient, but it can be read as Thibault says. It is a bit problematic to claim "le fait qu'il soit au participe passé fonctionne" because if participles can function as finite forms, then what is left for the auxiliary verb to do? Also, the question is nothing to do with passive v active voice.